# Writing a clojure function to email a file

Tags: email, clojure

I am trying to find a way to write a clojure function that will email a file passed to it as an argument. This is what I have so far but it does not seem to work.

```
(defn email-file[my_file]
(postal/send-message {:host "1.2.3.4"
                    :port 100
                    :user "a-user"
                    :pass "password"}
                   {:from "example@email.com"
                    :to "email@example.com"
                    :subject "Function to send file passed as argument"
                    :body [{:type :attachment
                           :content (java.io.File. my_file)}]}))
```

For now,it just returns (var project.email/email-report). What am I doing wrong?
Also, since I have the file already, how do I use that as the content of the email without attaching it. Attaching means I have to save it, download and open which which a bit too much.Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're defining an `email-report` function, you should call it to send an actual email: `(email-report file-to-send)`.

Comment: I get this exception when I call it: CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class java.io.File, compiling:(C:... . This is how I'm calling it (project/email-file my-file) and just before it there is (def my-file generate-file). Where generate returns the file

Comment: See example here look for :inline https://github.com/drewr/postal#attachments

Comment: @sparrow if `generate-file` returns a file, then it probably should be `(def my-file (generate-file))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is just text, consider using slurp to read it and use it as the body. Otherwise an inline html attachment should do the trick.

```
(defn email-file [filename]
  (postal/send-message
  ...
    :body (slurp filename)
  ...)

(email-file "~/my_file.txt")
```